# Watch changes in local Storage in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-services, angular2-services

I have a menu to appear based on being logged. 
I am using json web tokens in local storage for my authentication, I want to watch for a change to localStorage and then re-update my view on new information.

How can I watch for changes to localstorage?

I set my localStorage with this

localStorage.setItem('jwt', my_token);
The things I would like to do is check if I have a token, if I don't nothing happens, but when there is a change fire an event. From what I know I have to create a service, inject it where I want and susbscribe me to the observable.

What I have is the service, I don't know how to watch for the changes.

my service is:

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {
    private storage: any;

    constructor() {
        this.storage = localStorage;
    }

    public retrieve(key: string): any {
        var item = this.storage.getItem(key);

        if (item && item !== 'undefined') {
            return JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem(key));
        }

        return;
    }

    public store(key: string, value: any) {
        this.storage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }

}
```

Comment: Just curious.. What is `localStorage`? Don't see it being imported or declared anywhere in your snippet.

Comment: You needs to work at a higher abstraction layer. Where ever you are setting the token first time. You should raise an event using `EventEmitter. Other components a subscribe to it and react accordingly

Comment: It's the javascript object to work with the local storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I am not familiar with angular but if its possible you can bind event to window in javascript `window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {}` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: You mean that you want to implement an observable when some parts of your application call the `store` method of your `LocalStorageService` service?

Comment: Yes, I have a login that saves a token in localstorage, when the user is logged I want to show a menu.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a service that can do this for you if you still haven't found a suitable answer. The [h5webstorage](https://github.com/SirDarquan/h5webstorage) already handle watching both localStorage and sessionStorage events and synchronizes the changes. All you have to do is use it like a normal object.

Comment: dude, could you please help me running your code as when i tried running  it does not do any. may I need to follow some different steps please check
npm start
then it shows...
[0] 12:51:40 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.